# C# Winforms: Add an "Select from list..." placeholder to databound combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox which is databound like this:

```
comboBox.InvokeIfRequired(delegate
        {
            var data = db.GetData();
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
            comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox.DataSource = data;
        });
```

It works fine, but it preselects the first databound value. I want the combobox to be preselected with some placeholder like "Select item from list..."

What's the best way/approach to do that?
a) Adding to the data Variable empty item
b) Setting it through `combobox` variable properties? If so, which ones?
c) Other

Comment: But I don't have the placeholder in `Items` collection, so there is no value to be set in `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: It needs to be a value from the bound data, whichever one you want to preselect.  The SelectedValue property setter figures out what the SelectedIndex needs to be to match it.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that the best approach is to add a placeholder item to `db.GetData();` function and use it's value to set `combobox.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Oh, wait, I suddenly understand now what you mean by "placeholder".  That's not exactly ideal with a bound combobox.  do consider using a [cue instead](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/12/01/watermarked-edit-controls/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for this [here](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-1-cue-banners-in-windows-forms-em_setcuebanner-text-prompt/)

The code for this is:

```
private const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;        

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public UInt32 stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndItem;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    public static void SetCueText(Control control, string text)
    {
        if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO info = GetComboBoxInfo(control);
            SendMessage(info.hwndItem, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text);
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text);
        }
    }

    private static COMBOBOXINFO GetComboBoxInfo(Control control)
    {
        COMBOBOXINFO info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        //a combobox is made up of three controls, a button, a list and textbox;
        //we want the textbox
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        GetComboBoxInfo(control.Handle, ref info);
        return info;
    }
```

And then you can simple use it like this:

```
SetCueText(comboBox, "text");
```

This will also work for a textbox.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but is there a way to get this to work for combobox with the DropDownStyle set to DropDownList? It only works if it's set to DropDown.

Comment: I implemented you recommendation but found that it did not work. The applicable code is             county_CB.SelectedItem = -1;
            SCBT.set_combobox_text ( county_CB,
                                     Constants.SELECT_ONE );

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Text Property and write there "Select item from list..."

Comment: I'm affraid `Text` property will be overwritten while databinding. I've tried this approach and it didn't work